# Discord get the user who invited to the channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

How to find out by which link a user was invited to a group or how to find out which users connected using a specific invitation link?

In object [Invite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#invite) there are `uses` and `inviter` fields but how to get the `Member` instance that was invited?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a step for step explanation what you should do in your code:

- You have to track all joins and check after each join, who joined and which invite code use increases by 1.
- from the invite you get get the invite creator
- now, that you know who invited who, you can save one invite in a database and link the userid of the joined person to the inviter userid
- with a command you now can read the database and check which joined users are linked to your userid e.g.

--> you can't track the invites of the already joined members